# How to align an object by one or two edges to xyz axes?

Tags: modeling

How can I align object edge to one of the axis? For example, if I have a cube rotated 'freely' in the scene with applied rotation -- how can I realign it along x y and z axes again?

using physics engine comes to mind, but it also sounds like an overkill

Comment: Do you mean the objects origins? Or a specific vertex of the object?

Comment: in simplest case -- if I have an edge between two vertices -- how to align it to be parallel to one axis without changing shape of the object

Comment: You might be able to snap it to the surface of another aligned object, but I'm not sure.

Comment: See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEUa1IA7NBQ

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you can do it by tricks like parenting, constraint, snapping, addon, and scripting.

---

### Method 1 (parenting):

1. Select the edge you want to align;
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to align view to selected edge;
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to Selected;
4. Switch to **Object** mode, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to add an empty, <kbd>F6</kbd>, toggle **Align to View**, set it as parent to that object;
5. Select the empty, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>;
6. Select your object, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Clear and Keep Transformation. Then delete the empty.

---

### Method 2 (constraint):

1. (as method 1)
2. (as method 1)
3. (as method 1)
4. (as method 1)
5. Add another empty, add a **Copy Rotation** constraint to it, select the first empty as *Target*, leave other settings as default;
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply visual Transform, then delete the other two empties.

---

### Method 3 (snapping):

1. Select one vertex on the edge you want to align;
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to Selected;
3. Switch to **Object** mode, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to add a new empty, then move it for a certain distance along the expected axis;
4. Select all vertices of your object in **Edit** mode, with another vertex on that edge active (NOT the one in Step 1). Enable **Snap** mode on 3D View header, set *Snap Element* to **Vertex**, and make sure the *Snap Target* is set to **Active**;
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to toggle Quad View, switch *Pivot Point* to **3D Cursor**, snap the active vertex to the empty in two of the three Ortho views individually (it may depends on the actual case). Then delete that empty.

---

### Method 4 (addon):

Luckily there is an addon called [Precise Align](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Precise_Align) (the latest version is 1.1), which can well handle this:

1. Select one face that includes the edge you want to align;
2. Find **Precise Align** tool panel in the toolbar, click **Create Empty** button, click **Swap Empty Origin** if it is not aligned with the expected edge. Make sure **Parent to Object** is toggled;
3. Back to **Object** mode, select that empty, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>;
4. Select your object, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Clear and Keep Transformation. Then delete the empty.

---

### Method 5 (scripting):

Actually, I'm not good at scripting, but I'm sure it can be done. Welcome anyone that can complement with the scripting solution here. :)

Comment: item 4 "set it as parent to that object", how?

Comment: @AaA To parent the object to empty, first select the mesh object (Child), then select the empty (Parent) while holding **Shift**, then **Ctrl P**.