# Drag mesh by single vertex/point

Tags: vertices, coordinates

I'm talking about this:

[image]

In Google Skethcup, you can select a mesh, then any point on the mesh, and then move that mesh around as if the selected point is it's origin.

[image: n/a]

In the above picture, for instance, I'd like to be able to drag the entire mesh by the lowest vertex (The one the cursor is on).

Is it possible to select a mesh, and then move that mesh by a certain point?

Comment: @MrZak No - I'd like to be able to select a mesh, and then drag the entire selection by a selected point on the mesh.

Comment: @MrZak The point is I'd like to define a new selection origin - Select a point which I can move around and have the mesh follow it.

Comment: Select your mesh, change Pivot Point to `Active Element`, deselect and then select again desired vertex and now for moving mesh it will be used as point of origin

Comment: @MrZak Thanks, that did the trick. No way to do it through edit mode though? Your answer is sufficient, so if you'll submit it as an official answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to rotate around desired vertex / vertices you can make choose them as origins of transform and change Pivot Point.

#### Rotate around active

1. Enter Edit mode of the object.
2. Select everything that should be rotated. To select entire mesh select one of its vertices and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select linked  edges / faces.
3. Deselect desired vertex which should become origin point for this moment, and select it again. This will make it active.
4. In 3D View header change Pivot point to *Active Element* or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period). Rotate mesh.

   [image: demo GIF rotation around active]

#### Rotate around 3D Cursor

You can set 3D Cursor to that vertex and rotate around it. 
This method might be more flexible because you can use it in Object mode.

1. Enter Edit mode.
2. Select what you want to be origin point. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*.
3. Change Pivot point to 3D Cursor in 3D View header (or press <kbd>.</kbd> (period)).
4. Select what should be rotated, and rotate (if several objects should be rotated go to Object mode in this step).

   [image: demo GIF - around cursor]

See also related question:

- [Rotate object on axis between two points](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6949/rotate-object-on-axis-between-two-points)