# Bone doesn't rotate at right axis

Tags: armature, bones

I created an armature for my birds wing. The wing should be exactly rotated from the edge of the part of the wing. But everytime I rotate it by the x axis it leaves this line and there is some space between it (see the picture). This is because the part of the wing isn't parallel to the ground, but it goes up a bit in the Z axis. I don't know what to do, to tell the bone to rotate by another custom axis...[image]

My .blend file:
[image]

Comment: Please provide your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you

Comment: Here it is:[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3415" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3415/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options,

1) what you want is to rotate bone on custom axis, for this please see 
[Rotate object on axis between two points](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6949/rotate-object-on-axis-between-two-points)

**2)** if (1) this is cumbersome then i'll suggest, **join all mesh** (KFlügelR, FlügelL, Vogel, FlügelL, KFlügelL) together (select all mesh and do ctrl+j ). Then **assign the armature** to this joined mesh, use auto weight for first try . ( if you do not know how to do this then just ask :) )

3) Make the mesh so that its pivot is aligned to the bone orientation.

**I'll suggest option (2)**, as it should be the right way anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I joined the mesh and added the amature to it. After that I created a further bone for each wing and connected it as an IK (I did this with [SHIFT] + [I] and "To Active Bone" as I read it in my book.) and set the chain length to 2, so that the bones of the body of the bird aren't moved when I move the controll bone. This works but the body of the bird still gets formed. How can I stop this? (To make the problem sure I uploaded my file again: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3421/)

Comment: sorry didn't checked in detail, but from what i saw Bone.002 is attached to some vertices in body. To see this, click on armature, go to pose mode, now click on the bird mesh and then go to its weight paint (click on object mode in bottom menu to see weight paint option). Also you can see "manual weight paint, blender".

Comment: Also,  your control bone ('Bone in Armature.001'), should not affect the mesh directly. click on it and then click on the bone icon on right, scroll down, uncheck deform, then redo weight. Also the control bone does not have to be in different armature, it can be in same as the main Armature. Anyways nice low poly bird.

Comment: I couldn't get it working... But thanks for your great help. I maybe should try it with an easyier object first the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it! I added the armature "With Empty Groups" and assignes the vertexes in Edit Mode to the bones. (I found this in the first half of this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eF4CuIX40XE). Thanks again for all your help, my bird can fly ;-)