# Sliding an edge while keeping connected 90 faces in same orientation?

Tags: vertices, edges, selection-tools

I'm self taught and just recently learned of the edge/vertices slide tool. I was wondering if it was possible to slide an edge, while keeping a perpendicular "lip/bevel?" in the same orientation as it slides. (ie keep the bevel face perpendicular.) I hope the below screenshot gives a better picture.

[image]

If this is not currently possible, what method would you recommend to move this edge/bevel inward as I slide the shown edge? In the end i need to have the same vertices count, and a texture is already applied to mesh.

Thanks for any recommendations  !

Edit:
[image]
ie welding it with a shifted edge?

Comment: You can create [custom transform orientations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6959/935) that align to any item and use them to move the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different cases... In the first screenshot it's impossible to slide edge without affecting surrounding faces because of triangulated mesh. And as for the second one it's also impossible as you can only slide one edge (well, effectively).

If you haven't applied **Rotation** to the object you can simply change **Transform Orientation** to **Local** and move along selected axis:

[image: local]

But if you have it applied there are two methods to do this - regarding second case (quad based):

### Snap selection to Edge Loop.

1. Create additional Edge Loop and place it where you want to 'slide' your selection.
2. Turn on **Snapping: Vertex**.
3. Move selection to created Edge Loop.
4. **Remove Doubles** and **Dissolve** remaining unnecessary edge.

[image: Snap]

### Mesh Align Plus add-on.

Grab add-on from here: [Mesh Align Plus](https://github.com/egtwobits/mesh-align-plus/releases/tag/v0.4.0) and install it.

1. Go to **Mesh Align Plus** tab in **Tool Shelf** and select **Quick Directional Slide** section.
2. Uncheck **Auto Grab Source from selected Vertices**.
3. **Grab Normal Coordinates**.
4. Enter **Multiplier** value - it's small in my case.
5. Check E**nable Experimental Mesh Ops**.
6. Move selection by clicking **Mesh Piece**.

[image: map]

Comment: Is it possibe to snap the end of a edgeto a single vertices but have the line stay in same orientation but just shifts?

Comment: @Austin I think I don't understand clearly. Isn't it what "Snap to Edge Loop" method does?

Comment: Sorry I meant as in a edge that is not in a edge loop (single edge). This is what I ment: (see original post for image)

Comment: @Austin It's not possible, I've described it in the first paragraph. If you slide this vertex all connected edges will move with it. Try G > G and look how it's gonna behave.

Comment: Oh, I didn't fully understand what you were doing there. Now I see. Thanks.