# How to rotate/line up an object to an axis

Tags: objects, axis

I am trying to rotate the below object against an axis so that it looks like in the second image

[image]

[image]

In the second image I rotated the object manually, however I know this isn't ideal as it may not be perfectly aligned. Is there a better way to do this, using a trick/tool to ensure it lines up perfectly?

Many thanks

Comment: There are numerous ways (unfortunately tricks)  to align an object's axes to a component of its mesh, some of them are listed [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6376/35559) . You'll find a favourite before long. Having aligned the object axes, you can set the object's rotation to 0 along your chosen world axis, apply the rotation, reset its pivot, etc, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. If you rotated your object in Object Mode :

Hit Alt+R to reset rotation

## 2. If you rotated your object in Edit Mode :

#### That was a bad idea, cause you can't do .1.

Generally, if you want to rotate/scale your whole object, do it in Object mode.

If you want to rotate/scale a part of your object (some verts/faces), do it in Edit mode.

#### Ok but it's done now. What can I do ?

You can try box-selecting the vertices that you know should be aligned, and align them manually (s/z/num0 to align them on Z). It's tedious, that's why you should always prefer .1.