# How to change the Orientation of the Local Origin?

Tags: modeling

I have a mesh with a crooked origin. I understand how to center the Origin to its center of mass, a component selection or to the 3D Cursor. No issues here.

What I can't seem to find is how to Align, or Oriente the origin to affect the Local Origin of my Object permanently.

It seems that all Origin tools affect the Location of the Origin, but not the Rotation.

Thoughts?

-Berube

Comment: Related re fixing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63506/set-object-local-axis-based-on-face-orientation  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/how-to-align-an-object-by-one-or-two-edges-to-xyz-axes

Comment: btw the origin is simply a point in space that is local coordinate (0, 0, 0). It has no rotation.  The links posted above move the coordinates of geometry to align with local axes.