Re-aligning an object
Suppose I have an object that has been rotated and the transforms have been applied. The local origin is now the same as the global. How can i align the object so it runs parallel to the bottom plane (blue line)?


Maybe something here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/how-to-align-an-object-by-one-or-two-edges-to-xyz-axes?rq=1 will help.

You could pick an edge you want the object space to be aligned to, snap the 3d cursor( Shift  +  S  menu) to one end vertex, duplicate the vertex( Shift  +  D ) and move it constrained to one axis, then select everything except that duplicated vertex, make the other end vertex active and rotate everything with 3d cursor as transformation pivot while snapping rotation to the duplicated vert with Active selected as Snap Base:


There are other snapping settings combinations that can work for this as well. The idea is just to use rotation snapping in some way to snap it to whatever you create that is aligned to some axis.

Thanks. Pivot Transform addon might solve this problem.
